# GeoFirestore Returning Too Many Results

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am using GeoFirestore to run geo queries against my Firebase Firestore. It seems to generally work but is returning more results than it should once I test with a radius of more than 25 miles. The closest location in my Firestore is 103 miles from the location I'm testing with. I've tested in 25 mile increments. 25 miles doesn't return any locations, 50 miles returns the closest one, 75 returns the closest one, and 100 miles returns all three of my test locations. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
func getFacilites() {
        self.facilities = [[String: Any]]()

        let currentLatitude = self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let currentLongitude = self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

        let geoFireStore = Constants.geoFirestore
        let circleQuery = geoFireStore.query(withCenter: GeoPoint(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude), radius: milesToKilometers())
        let _ = circleQuery.observeReady {
            print("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!")
        }
        let _ = circleQuery.observe(.documentEntered, with: { (key, location) in
            Constants.firestore.collection("facilities").document(key!).getDocument { (document, error) in
                if let document = document, document.exists {
                    self.facilities?.append(document.data()!)
                    self.addFaciltiesToMap()
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist.")
                }
            }
        })
    }

func milesToKilometers() -> Double {
     // self.searchDistance is a Double value
     return self.searchDistance * 1.60934
}
```

Comment: Show your milesToKilometers() function.

Comment: @rv7284 I’ve added it.

Comment: @raginggoat I'm experiencing similar incorrect behaviour using the GeoFirestore query(withCenter: testLocation, radius: 10.0).  Did you discover why this was happening in your case or find a work around?